# Installing a Recursive Function Using symbol-function

Tags: lambda, common-lisp, anonymous-function, sbcl

A function can be installed programmatically in Common Lisp using `symbol-function` (instead of `defun`):

```
* (setf (symbol-function 'factorial)
    (compile nil (lambda (n) 
                   (if (= n 1) 
                     1 
                     (* n (factorial (- n 1)))))))

; in: SETF (SYMBOL-FUNCTION 'FACTORIAL)
;     (FACTORIAL (- N 1))
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: COMMON-LISP-USER::FACTORIAL
;
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     FACTORIAL
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition
#<FUNCTION (LAMBDA (N)) {1003F2222B}>
```

But as above, if the function is recursive, a warning is issued by SBCL because the function is anonymous.

This problem is not encountered when using `defun`, since, as the hyperspec says:
"Evaluating defun causes function-name to be a global name for the function specified by the lambda expression".

Can the warning be averted by providing the proper function name when using `symbol-function`?

(PS: At first, I thought the `compile` function could be given the function name, but that is only for macros.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declaring that `factorial` is `fbound` is enough to remove the warning:

```
(compile nil 
         (lambda (n) 
           (declare (ftype function factorial)) 
           (if (= n 1) 
               1 
               (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
```

Comment: I notice a declaration works, but only if it is global:  `(declaim (ftype function factorial))`.  Not sure why, though.

Comment: However, my problem with top-level `declaim` is that I have a list of the function names to declaim. So the name of each function is going to be the value of a loop variable. The hyperspec says that the declamation must be a top-level form, in order for the proclamations to be made at compile time.

Comment: You probably compiled the above snippet (compile ...), which saw a call to the function inside the lambda. You can use proclaim in an eval-when block instead. I must say I am a bit worried about what you are trying to do :-)

Comment: Yes, proclaim in eval-when with :compile-toplevel works fine. I had forgotten that proclaim is a function. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [my `define-functions` hack](https://github.com/tfeb/tfeb-lisp-hax#defining-global-functions-with-lexical-environments-define-functions), but the general trick is that you need to teach the system that the thing is a function, and you generally need to do this *globally* as well as within the body of the function, so the compiler won't complain when, later on, there are calls to this thing.  That's what `define-function` / `define-functions` arranges to do.  If you want to do it by hand, you probably want this:

```
(declaim (ftype function factorial))
(setf (fdefinition 'factorial) (compile nil ...))
```

This is pretty much what `define-function` expands into (in fact it expands into `define-functions` which then does the work for it).

---

Note that you *can* give the function's name to `compile`: it's nothing to do with macros.  You'll still get the same warning however:

```
(compile 'fact (lambda (n)
                 (if (= n 1) 
                     1 
                     (* n (fact (- n 1))))))
```

will install the function as the `fdefinition` of `fact`, but the compiler does not know that at the time the function is being compiled.

Comment: Does this mean the only change to my existing code would be to transform `(setf (symbol-function fname) (compile nil lambda-expr))` to `(define-function (fname) lambda-expr)`, given the default ftype = function?

Comment: If you want to be *sure* it's compiled you want `(define-function name  (compile nil ...))`, but yes.

Answer (score 2):

It might be useful to use a local recursive function

```
CL-USER 2 > (setf (symbol-function 'factorial)
                  (compile nil
                           (lambda (n)
                             (labels ((%factorial (n)
                                        (if (= n 1) 
                                            1 
                                          (* n (%factorial (- n 1))))))
                                   (%factorial n)))))
#<Function 13 40600030D4>

CL-USER 3 > (factorial 4)
24
```

This way one would make clear where the recursive call goes to.

One could hide that behind some kind of named `lambda` macro. Which might be used like this:

```
(compile nil 
         (nlambda factorial (n) 
           (if (= n 1) 
               1 
               (* n (factorial (- n 1))))))
```